# Can we use ROS for our own robot

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Can we use ROS for our own robot? ie, without buying the bases like PR2, Husky, TurtleBot, Kobuki etc. I can use a laptop inside my robot. I need to control the robot by a program installed in laptop. Whether i can use ROS in such a condition? Can i use ROS for controlling motors and various sensors in my robot?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/68581/can-we-use-ros-for-our-own-robot/) by [Sreejith](https://answers.ros.org/users/5533/sreejith/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2013-07-23

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Yes, of course! But you will need some way to create an interface between ROS and your own motors and sensors. You need for instance an arduino to let the computer control the motors. For arduino there are some examples available. Another option is to use a motor driver which is supported in ROS.
For TF you need a model of your own robot.

---

Originally posted by [davinci](https://answers.ros.org/users/3014/davinci/) with karma: 2573 on 2013-07-23

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1